# run .jar file with "java" command Centos

Tags: java, jar, centos

I'm trying to run a .jar file on my centos box, but it says "java: command not found".

What's the best or easiest way to solve this? I was hoping for a yum command but not sure that that will exist for java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use such command to check if Java is available in your repository:

```
yum list | grep java
```

It should return something like that:

```
java-1.6.0-openjdk
java-1.6.0-sun
```

If such package exists you can install it using such command (run it as the root user):

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

Comment: thanks lukasz, that was the package I was looking for. Solved!

Answer (score 5):

Apparently some versions of CentOS doesn't come with a JVM installed due to some licensing restriction.  See [HowTo Install Java on CentOS 4 and CentOS 5](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/JavaOnCentOS) for instructions.

Comment: The "licensing restriction" is outdated.  It is in the linked document starting at *"SPECIAL NOTE: Starting with CentOS 5.3 ..."*.

Comment: @Stephen: That still explains what you need to do.  Either upgrade CentOS so you can use OpenJDK or follow the instructions for installing one of the other JRE/JDKs.  I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Either the JRE is not installed or, more likely, its location is not included in your `PATH` environment variable. If the `java` executable is not in your `PATH`, you would need to use the full path & filename to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

cd to the location of the jar file

C:\temp>java -jar sample.jar